# How to format text in WPF menu items?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a menu item like this:

```
menu.Items.Insert(0, new MenuItem
{
    Header = String.Format("Foo \"{0}\" bar", "qux")
});
```

My question is this: how can I apply some text formatting stuff like `Foreground` color to the `{0}` part?

Comment: control templates  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a `TextBlock` with differently formatted `Inline` elements:

```
TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
text.Inlines.AddRange(
    new Inline[]
        {
            new Run("Foo "),
            new Run(string.Format("\"{0}\"", "qux")) {Foreground = Brushes.Red},
            new Run(" bar")
        });

menu.Items.Insert(0, new MenuItem
{
    Header = text
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Header` property is the content element for the MenuItem and is of type `object`.

Consider how you would format a menu item using Xaml, one example might be:

```
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Background="Yellow" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold">
                Foo
            </Run>
            ... etc
        </TextBlock>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

Emulate that in code.